# MATLAB Function within function and if statement withn strcmp

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement

My code seems to give me new errors all the time. Through debugging I realise that the error is somewhere by the if statements where I specify 'b'. Sometimes when the code runs it only returns back one singular value for all inputs.

It also randomly asks for end statements and doesn't accept elseif statements. I really need to know what exactly is messing up.

Kindly do help!

```
x = inputdlg({'Pathogen','Month (First letter capital)', 'Population Renewal', 'Death Rate'}, 'Inputs - Please enter the following information');
g = getfield(x,{1});
f = getfield(x,{2});
if strcmp('g','Salmonella')
    if any (strcmp(f,{'November','December','January','February','March','April'}))
%if ismember (f,{'January','February'})
    b = 0.01
elseif any (strcmp(f,{'May','June','July','August'}))
    b = 0.0001
    else 
        b = 0.001
    end
end

%b = str2double(x{1});
p = str2double(x(3));
l = 0.5;
d = 0.9;
m = str2double(x(4));
f = (b*p)*(1+(l*d)); 
h = m*(m+l);
R = f/h;

if (R<1)
answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is no epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
else
    answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is an epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
end


yo = [20 5 5 10]; 
[t x]= prmgr(p,m,yo);
plot(t,x(:,1),'k','Linewidth',1.5)
hold
[t y] = msifunc(b,p,m,l,d,yo);
plot(t,y(:,1),'-r*','Linewidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',5)
title('Susceptible Population')
legend('Disease free state','Test state')



if strcmp('g','Shigella')   
if any (strcmp(f,{'November','December','January','February','March'}))
%if ismember (f,{'January','February'})
    b = 0.01
elseif any (strcmp(f,{'May','April','October'}))
    b = 0.001
    else 
        b = 0.00001
end

end
%b = str2double(x{1});
p = str2double(x(3));
n = 0.14;
m = str2double(x(4));
f = b*p; 
h = m*(m+n);
R = f/h;

if (R<1)
answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is no epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
else
    answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is an epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
end

yo = [20 5 10]; 
[t u] = ugr(p,m,yo);
plot(t,u(:,1),'k','Linewidth',1.5)
hold
[t v] = shigfunc(b,p,m,yo)
plot(t,v(:,1),'-r*','Linewidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',5)
title('Susceptible Population')
legend('Disease free state','Test state')


if strcmp('g','Rotavirus')
    if any (strcmp(f,{'May','June','July','August'}))
    b = 0.1
elseif any (strcmp(f,{'October','March'}))
    b = 0.001
    else 
        b = 0.01
    end
end

%b = str2double(x{1});
p = str2double(x(3));
l = 0.5;
d = 0.9;
q = 0.4
m = str2double(x(4));
f = (b*p*q); 
h = m*(m+l);
R = f/h;

if (R<1)
answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is no epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
else
    answer = msgbox(['Value = ' num2str(R) ' therefore there is an epidemic'],'Basic Reproduction number')
end


yo = [20 5 5 10]; 
[t w]= rota(p,m,yo);
plot(t,w(:,1),'k','Linewidth',1.5)
hold
[t z] = rotfunc(b,p,m,l,d,yo);
plot(t,z(:,1),'-r*','Linewidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',5)
title('Susceptible Population')
legend('Disease free state','Test state')
```

Comment: can you post the latest console error?

Comment: you can use `strcmpi` to not have to worry about upper/lower case letters.

Comment: You have a mistake in `if strcmp('g','Salmonella')`: `g` is a variable, so you need to remove the `''`: `if strcmp(g,'Salmonella')`

Comment: Ill try the suggestions and get back. Sometimes there is no error shown but the calculations are not correct. For example, it seems like the if statement for the variable g is not working. Ill try the corrections reort back with the console errors.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!! It makes things much better!
There are two small issues remaining now:
1. The first graph for shigella only plots up to 5 all the time
2. In the last if statement (for rotavirus), an error appears that input yo is undefined.
Apart from these, it seems to be much better!